# Can a born again Promethean take a new supernatural template?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, promethean-the-created

Prometheans are pretty unique among the Chronicles of Darkness games in that they can become human again.

Can a Redeemed Created take on another template? If they do so, do they keep their Athanor?

Comment: For the record, I don't think Sin Eaters can become human again; they keep their Geist until they die for the last time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *is* covered in the book. On Page 197, under **Aftermath**:

> As a mortal, the character still nurtures some spark of the Pyros within him. Such a character can Awaken or be Embraced, though. If this is the case, that spark of Pyros is *extinguished by the Embrace*, or *transformed by the Awakening*. Vampires and mages who come to be in this way are normal for that type of creature. They gain no benefit from having once been Prometheans.

(emphasis mine)

The White Wolf Wiki Article on the [Redeemed](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Redeemed) has this to say:

> In addition, as in any of the above situations, any boons the former Redeemed have are lost.

And references page 70-72 of the main Promethean book (PtC), which seems to say nothing on retaining Athanor.

I'd argue it's up to the Story Teller if the player retains the mortal version of Athanor. Some seem more supernatural and/or tired to Pyros than others.

Comment: @Pureferret I'm gonna argue that "no benefit" means "no benefit"—any benefit from the Athanor is lost when the person becomes a new kind of supernatural, "normal for that type of creature."

Comment: @Jadasc that's probably a closer reading of the rules