# Do the mortal versions of Athanor rely on the spark of Pyros?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, promethean-the-created

This came up in [Can a born again Promethean take a new supernatural template?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59912/2788)

I couldn't find a reference in Promethean: the Created, and I don't know where else it'd be.

Does Athanor rely on the 'spark of Pyros'? Not necessarily expending anything, just not having it snuffed out by applying further major templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
Yes, they do.

Just like your ability to be reraised as a promethan after death,
you lose access to your Athanor when you gain a major template.

> As a mortal, the character still nurtures some spark of
>   the Pyros within him. Such a character can Awaken or be
>   Embraced, though. If this is the case, that spark of Pyros is
>   extinguished by the Embrace, or transformed by the Awakening.
>   Vampires and mages who come to be in this way are
>   normal for that type of creature. **They gain no benefit from
>   having once been Prometheans.**

Emphaise mine.

I think it makes it pretty clear, your athanor stops mortal boon.
Makes sense, since it is your *mortal* boon,
and the athanor is a safe-guard against the risks of mortality. Which as a supernatural you no longer have.

If you go deep into the supernatural meta of nwod, (in particular the supernatural demiurge stuff) this is inline.

---

Had this happen to a character of mine. Moderately disappointing.
But happy cos in the same scene I succeeded my roll to regain my lost memories.

Comment: I took that line to mean that they gain no benefit from generally having been  Promethean... No mention of Athanor. Still good answer :-)

Comment: Unfortunately rule books so very often have these unexplictnesses, and never clarify.
I think the worst for it is the Rivam (promethian) and the question of if they speak first tongue. Never explictly stated.